# XAMPP ; PHP not available in console for non-admin users

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, windows-10, environment-variables

I'm using Windows 10. I've installed XAMPP in C:\xampp and added an environmental Path variable C:\xampp\php.

However, the problem is, PHP isn't available to users other than admin.

What can I do to make that pre-installed PHP available to all users?

If it's too much of a hassle, is there any way to allow VSC to use that pre-installed PHP? I've changed File>Preferences>Extensions>PHP>PHP›'Validate: Executable Path' to:

"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\xampp\php\php.exe"

but it's still not working. I've tried to set php.executablePath, but it's greyed out.

Comment: Did you install the PHP extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense

Comment: @tHeSiD No, but I've just installed it and added php.executablePath. It didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want PHP executables to available for all your users you need to set the PATH in SYSTEM VARIABLES.

Please check by going to the system properties screen (Win+Pause/Break) and then Select `Advanced System Settings` -> `Advanced`

And add your path `C:\Xampp\php\` to the path list as shown in this picture.

[image: Path on Windows]